# Manipulate itemView through CollectionView

Tags: ember.js

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/lifeinafolder/mpcRr/

Essentially, I want to hide the current 'visible' item and make the next one 'visible' but toggleProperty doesn't seem to be working on the childView object. It just silently fails and throws no errors as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quite ugly solution, almost working. I kept the way of switching views.

The template is the same, the js looks like this:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.slides = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({
    content:[]
});

App.slidesCollectionView = Ember.CollectionView.extend({
    contentBinding:"App.slides",
    tagName:'div',
    emptyView: Ember.View.extend({
        template: Ember.Handlebars.compile("<div class=\"placeholder\">placeholder</div>")
    }),
    itemViewClass:"App.slideView",
    classNames:["slideshow"],
    click:function(){
        var t = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({ content: this.get('childViews') });
        var selected = t.findProperty('isVisible', true);
        if(selected){
            var nextSlide = t.objectAt(selected.get('contentIndex') + 1);
            selected.set('isVisible', false);
            if(nextSlide){
                nextSlide.set('isVisible', true);
            }else{
                t.get('firstObject').set('isVisible', true);
            }
        }else{
            t.get('firstObject').set('isVisible', true);

        }            
    }
});

App.slideView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'slide-item',
    tagName:'div',
    isVisible: false,
    classNames:['slide'],
    classNameBindings:['isVisible:selected']
});

setTimeout(function(){
App.slides.pushObjects([
    Ember.Object.create({val:'a',index:0}),
    Ember.Object.create({val:'b',index:1}),
    Ember.Object.create({val:'c',index:2}),
    Ember.Object.create({val:'d',index:3}),
    Ember.Object.create({val:'e',index:4}),
    Ember.Object.create({val:'f',index:5})
])},2000);
```

the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/dd6at/

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work. Infact, the initial childView with 'a' is also not showing up.

Comment: @Rajat "It almost works". In fact all views are initialized with isVisible=false. But if you click when the placeholder disappear, I think it's fine.

Answer (score 2):

A CollectionView will show all items in the collection, which is not what you want. I would implement a standard view that houses the collection and displays the next button and a slide view within it that displays the selected slide when the container view sets the selected slide as content on the slide view.